# Should GUID be used as a foreign key to many tables

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, asp.net-membership

I designed a database to use GUIDs for the `UserID` but I added `UserId` as a foreign key to many other tables, and as I plan to have a very large number of database inputs I must design this well.

I also use ASP Membership tables (not profiles only membership, users and roles).

So currently I use a GUID as PK and as FK in every other table, this is maybe bad design?
What I think is maybe better and is the source of my question, should I add in Users table `UserId(int)` as a primary key and use this field as a foreign key to other tables and user `GUID UserId` only to reference `aspnet_membership`?

```
aspnet_membership{UserID(uniqueIdentifier)}
Users{
UserID_FK(uniqueIdentifier) // FK to aspnet_membership table
UserID(int) // primary key in this table --> Should I add this
...
}
In other tables user can create items in tables and I always must add UserId for example:
TableA{TableA_PK(int)..., CreatedBy(uniqueIdentifier)}
TableB{TableB_PK(int)..., CreatedBy(uniqueIdentifier)}
TableC{TableC_PK(int)..., CreatedBy(uniqueIdentifier)}
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately the answer is that it really depends.

Microsoft have documented the performance differences of each [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2010/05/27/guid-vs-int-debate.aspx). While the article differs slightly to your situation, as you have to use a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER to link back to asp membership, many of the discussion points still apply.

If you have to create your own users table anyway it would make more sense to have your own int primary key, and use the GUID as a foreign key. It keeps separate entities separate. What if at some point in the future you wanted to add a different membership to a user? You would then need to update a primary key, which would have to cascade to any tables referencing this and could be quite a performance hit. If it is just a unique column in your users table it is a simple update.

Comment: SO do you suggest me to use uniqueidentifier to join to asp membership table and int to reference other tables in database? My greatest concern here in my current situation is performance nothing else.

Comment: Personally I would use int to reference other tables, there will not be massive performance differences, but int will out perform uniqueidentifier.

Answer (score 2):

All binary datatypes (uniqueidetifier is binary(16)) are fine as foreign keys. But GUID might cause another small problem as primary key. By default primary key is clustered, but GUID is generated randomly not sequentially as IDENTITY, so it will frequently split IO pages, that cause performance degradation a little.

Comment: Actually, a clustered GUID key is not a small problem - it's a **HUGE** performance issue.

Comment: Highly depends on record size, fillfactor, write strategy, etc. Usually, with proper maintenance it is around 5% performance lost.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go ahead with your current design.

If you're worried because of inner joins performance in your queries because of comparing strings instead of ints, nowadays there is no difference at all.